# Segmentation fault with strcmp, but the string prints using printf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcmp

I have a tokenizer method that returns a `char**`.  The results are being stored in a `char**` called `lineTokens`.  When I use `printf()` to print the first token, I get the correct result, but when I use `strcmp(lineTokens[0],"Some text")`, I get a seg fault.  The appropriate code is below.

```
lineTokens = tokenize(tempString);
printf("token[0] = %s\n", lineTokens[0]);
if(strcmp(lineTokens[0], "INPUTVAR")==0){
    printf("It worked\n");
}
```

EDIT:
My tokenize code is as follows

```
char** tokenize(char* input){
int i = 0;
char* tok;
char** ret;
tok = strtok(input, " ");
ret[0] = tok;
while(tok != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", tok);
    ret[i] = tok;
    tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
    i++;
}
ret[i] = NULL;
return ret;
```

}

Comment: `I get the correct result,`...a possible side-effect of an [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried using a debugger such as gdb or a memory tool such as valgrind?

Comment: The bug is most likely outside the code posted.

Comment: More details are needed.  Post your `tokenize()` code.

Comment: Show us your function and the main where you call the function!

Comment: I bet `tokenize` has a local variable like `char* result[10];` and [it does a `return result;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope). This returns the address of a local variable. The memory for the local variable is still valid at the `printf`, but `printf` consumes enough stack that by the time it returns, the memory is no longer valid.

Comment: `char** ret; ... ret[0] = tok;` is bad. `ret` is not initialized or assigned.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to answer this without seeing the code of `tokenize()`, of course.

My guess is that there is some undefined behavior in that function, which perhaps corrupts the stack, so that when `printf()` runs and actually uses some more stack space, things go bad. The thing with undefined behavior is that it's really undefined, anything can happen.

Run the code in Valgrind.

Comment: Or debug the executable using the Gdb debugger. http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/pointers/summary.html                              Small gdb tutorial to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Your tokenize function is broken. Every pointer in your code needs to point at allocated memory, which is not the case here. You get no memory allocated by simply declaring a pointer: a pointer is merely containing *an address* to memory allocated some place else. Given that you set it to point at "some place else", if you don't, it will point at a random garbage address.

So you need to rewrite that function from scratch. Either pass a pointer to allocated memory as a parameter or allocate memory dynamically inside the function. But before you do, I would strongly recommend that you study arrays and pointers some more, for example by reading [this chapter](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) of the C FAQ.

Comment: yup. I'm an idiot.  Malloc in the tokenize function solved it.  Just learning C and used to Java.  Good ol Java.

Comment: @ScottCorbett Classic Java-programmer-learning-C bug :) Just remember that C has no garbage collection either, so you will need to `free()` all memory allocated. At any rate I strongly recommend reading everything at http://c-faq.com/, it is excellent reading for beginners and veterans all alike.